# Unable to fetch same reports using Google Ads API

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-query-language

In the google ads UI, i selected day, country, cost columns and it works fine. How to translate this into query? Currently i', using this query.

```
SELECT 
  campaign.shopping_setting.sales_country, 
  metrics.cost_micros, 
  customer.currency_code 
FROM campaign
WHERE 
  segments.date >= "{start_date}" 
  AND segments.date <= "{end_date}"
```

But this `sales_country` is not same as the country in UI. How to get country column ? The cost and dates are correct. Only the country column is a problem. I also tried 'geographic_view` in FROM clause, but still not getting the reports. Can anyone help ?

[image]